# How to fix "The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type"?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-8.0

I know this question has several posts with multiple answers but in my case I haven't found the solution.

- *I'm building a Web Api with NET 8.*
- *My Web Api has swagger.*
- *I'm using Dependency Injection, Service layer, UnityOfWork and
  Repository pattern.*
- *I'm not using CORS in this moment.*

So the stack trace pattern to get the data it looks like this:

`_myService.GetUsers() => _unityOfWork.UsersRepository.GetAll() => _context.Users.ToList()`

In my case, I have only 3 controllers performing simple CRUD operations

In every class I have something like this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{     
    private readonly IUserService _userService;     
    private readonly IUserTypeService _userTypeService;     
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;     

    /*Constructor with injections*/
    public UsersController(IUserService userService, 
                           IUserTypeService userTypeService, 
                           IMapper mapper) 
    {     
        _userService = userService;     
        _mapper = mapper;     
        _userTypeService = userTypeService; 
    }

    [HttpPost] 
    public IActionResult TestAction([FromBody] UserRegisterDto registeredUserDto) 
    {     
          /*---Some code snippet here ---*/
    }
}
```

Swagger is displaying my Controllers and Endpoints as expected
[image: SwaggerUI]

But it doesn't matter what actions I execute, it throws the same error for all the actions; some of them are HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPatch, etc.

**Body request:**

*Note: All the properties are string types in the backend class (UserRegisterDto.cs)*

```
{   
  "username": "string",   
  "name": "string",   
  "password": "string",   
  "role": "string" 
}
```

And this is the error thrown.
[image]

**This is my Program.cs file**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; 
using System; using System.Reflection; 
using Sat.Recruitment.Infrastructure.Extensions; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;  

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddOptions(builder.Configuration); 
    builder.Services.AddDbContexts(builder.Configuration);          
    builder.Services.AddServices(builder.Configuration); 
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(builder.Configuration); builder.Services.AddSwagger($"    
                                {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"); 
    
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());    
    builder.Services.AddControllers(options => {        
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default30seconds", new CacheProfile { Duration = 30 
            }); }).AddNewtonsoftJson();  

var app = builder.Build();  // Configure the HTTP request pipeline. 

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
{     
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();     
    app.UseSwagger();     
    app.UseSwaggerUI(); 
}  

app.UseHttpsRedirection();   
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();  
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { _ = endpoints.MapControllers(); });  
app.Run();
```

I don't know what exactly I have to fix. I already checked my dependencies and it seems everything it's ok. I have a breakpoint in the UserController constructor but it's not reached by the request.

**Dependencies file (Extension methods for services in Program.cs file)**
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as (properly formatted) text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type

This error is usually caused by uncertain references during use constraints. I reproduced the same error as you, you can use it as a reference.
This error occurs when my routing template is configured with a string type constraint :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UController : Controller
    {

   [HttpGet("{id:string}")]
   public IActionResult GetById(string id)
   {

       return Ok($"User with ID {id}");
   }   
    }
```

[image]
And the same error will be reported in my other methods:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
      
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TestAction([FromBody] UserRegisterDto registeredUserDto)
    {
       
        return Ok(registeredUserDto);
    }
}
```

[image]
When I delete string :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class UController : Controller
  {
      [HttpGet("{id}")]
      public IActionResult GetById(string id)
      {

          return Ok($"User with ID {id}");
      }

  }
```

All methods return to normal:
[image]
[image]

In ASP.NET Core, route parameters are of type string by default. Therefore, using {parameter:string} is not a valid routing constraint because the default is already of type string. If you use string type constraints in other controllers and methods, conflicts may occur.
To resolve this issue, you can check if any of your other controllers and methods have incorrect constraints configured. If such constraints exist, you can consider deleting them or using alpha to configure more specific constraints. For specific information about route constraints, you can refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-constraints

Answer (score 2):

There is no constraint called string in asp net. However, Please consider the following points if you want to control how the id argument must look like:

1- If the ID must be a GUID, you may use `{id:guid}`

2-If the ID must be an integer, you may use `{id:int}`

3-If you want any parameter to accept only alphabets (a to z characters), use `{id:alpha}`

4- If none of the above match, you may use regular expression to ensue the correctness of the id format like this `{regex: *your reqular expression*}`